# Files (Nautilus): text files on the remote server appear as `application/octet-stream` and cannot be opened by the default text editor

Tags: 22.04, nautilus

Lately, text files on the remote server appear as `application/octet-stream` and cannot be opened by the default text editor (Geany):

[image]

[image]

I've tried choosing not only Geany, but also other text editors (for example, Sublime Text), but they just opened without the file content.

---

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

---

I added `application/octet-stream=org.gnome.gedit.desktop` to `~/.config/mimeapps.list` under `[Default Applications]` section:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=geany.desktop
application/octet-stream=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
```

Now such files can be opened by double clicking in `gedit`.

But earlier, if I'm not mistaken, the type in Files was shown as `plain text document` and they could be opened in Geany.